# Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)'

Tags: mysql, excel, vba

I'm trying to update mysql database using excel, this worked well on just one column from mysql database, but if other .. excel vba returns this error

> "Run-time error '-2147217900 (80040e14)'"

here's my code

```
Sub ud()
Dim cmdCommand As New ADODB.Command
Dim recSet As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim i As Integer
Dim sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim code, datesold As String
tf = Range("O2")
sf = Range("H3")


ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Activate
Set sheet1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Set Rng = Range("Table_Query_from_20172018_1")
Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
cn.ConnectionString = "Driver=MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI
Driver;SERVER=localhost;PWD=12345678;UID=root;DATABASE=bio;PORT=3306"
cn.Open
cmdCommand.ActiveConnection = cn
Loop sheet1 data rows
For i = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count
ID = Rng.Cells(i, 5).Value
shf = Rng.Cells(i, 6).Value
wazaef = Rng.Cells(i, 7).Value
emtihan = Rng.Cells(i, 11).Value

 strSQLCommand = "UPDATE students INNER JOIN (e1a INNER JOIN (eshfwi INNER JOIN wanda ON eshfwi.ID = wanda.ID) ON e1a.ID = wanda.ID) ON students.ID = e1a.ID SET eshfwi." & tf & " = " & shf & ", wanda." & tf & " = " & wazaef & ", e1a." & tf & " = " & emtihan & " where eshfwi.ID = " & ID & " and wanda.ID=" & ID & " and e1a.ID=" & ID & ";"
 cmdCommand.CommandText = strSQLCommand
 cmdCommand.CommandType = adCmdText
 Set recSet = cmdCommand.Execute

Next i
End Sub
```

update: sql statement is working with another column in the same table .. but when i update another one this error is showing .. now i tried to delete the column and create a new one .. the code worked with some ID's then the same error appear with a report contains this message

https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4cy0.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code .. and its working now by creating a table with a connection string contains the sql updating command then used "for next" to loop the command by ID:

```
Sub ud()
Dim i As Integer

Dim j As Integer

Dim k As Integer

 Dim sheet1 As Worksheet

 tf = Range("O2")

 sf = Range("H3")

Range("P8").Select

Application.CutCopyMode = False

With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "ODBC;DSN=20172018;", Destination:=Range("$P$8")).QueryTable

.CommandText = Array("SELECT e1.ID FROM e1 where id=1")

.RowNumbers = False

.FillAdjacentFormulas = False

.PreserveFormatting = True

.RefreshOnFileOpen = False

.BackgroundQuery = False

.RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells

.SavePassword = False

.SaveData = True

.AdjustColumnWidth = True

.RefreshPeriod = 0

.PreserveColumnInfo = True

.ListObject.DisplayName = "Query_from_20172018t"

.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With


 Act
 iveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Activate

 Set sheet1 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

 Set Rng = Range("Table_Query_from_20172018_1")





 For i = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count

 ID = Rng.Cells(i, 5).Value

 shf = Rng.Cells(i, 6).Value

 wazaef = Rng.Cells(i, 7).Value

 emtihan = Rng.Cells(i, 11).Value

 With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").ODBCConnection

 .CommandText = Array("UPDATE students INNER JOIN e1a ON students.ID = e1a.ID SET e1a." & tf & " = " & emtihan & " where students.class='" & sf & "' and e1a.ID=" & ID & ";")

 End With

 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

 Next i



 For j = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count

 ID = Rng.Cells(j, 5).Value

 shf = Rng.Cells(j, 6).Value

 wazaef = Rng.Cells(j, 7).Value

 emtihan = Rng.Cells(j, 11).Value

 With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").ODBCConnection

 .CommandText = Array("UPDATE students INNER JOIN eshfwi ON students.ID = eshfwi.ID SET eshfwi." & tf & " = " & emtihan & " where students.class='" & sf & "' and eshfwi.ID=" & ID & ";")

 End With

 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

 Next j



For k = 1 To Rng.Rows.Count

ID = Rng.Cells(k, 5).Value

shf = Rng.Cells(k, 6).Value

 wazaef = Rng.Cells(k, 7).Value

 emtihan = Rng.Cells(k, 11).Value

 With ActiveWorkbook.Connections("Connection").ODBCConnection

 .CommandText = Array("UPDATE students INNER JOIN wanda ON students.ID = wanda.ID SET wanda." & tf & " = " & emtihan & " where students.class='" & sf & "' and wanda.ID=" & ID & ";")

End With

 ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll

 Next k


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Most probably there is an error with the SQL statement.
Put a statement `Debug.print strSQLCommand` before you write it to `commandText`, check the content in the Immediate Window and try to execute it on the sql console. As we don't know your data types, it's hard to tell but maybe you are missing quotes. Assuming `tf` is a text field, the code should be
`... SET eshfwi." & tf & " = '" & shf & "'" ...`
(Hint: It's much better to use parameter, see for example https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/144063/passing-multiple-parameters-to-an-sql-query)

Comment: thanks for reply can you see the picture in the new update of the question please ?

Comment: So it's an SQL syntax error, but it's impossible from here to tell exactly the problem. Try to execute it against your database directly (not from VBA) and correct it.